# How to fix archiving folders by year?

Tags: email, thunderbird, archiving

Thunderbird stopped archiving by the year regardless the setting. It simply moves all mails to the archive root folder regardless of settings.
It last archived emails from 2022 correctly. 2023's messages are no longer stored by the year.

By `Yearly archived folders` i mean this: [Configure archive folder structure Yearly archived folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfT5C.png)
More about it at [support.mozilla.org/.../archived-messages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages)

Any idea how to fix that without creating new profile and/or resetting all settings?

I found this:
[superuser.../533106/how-can-i-archive-my-emails-in-thunderbird-to-monthly-archive-folders](https://superuser.com/questions/533106/how-can-i-archive-my-emails-in-thunderbird-to-monthly-archive-folders) - it seems to be more of general how to, while i know how to but it doesn't work.

I tried to:

- Run TB in safe mode with no plugins
- Switching archiving option between folders by year / root archive.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that settings doesn't correctly change the actual configuration.

In the config editor, search for `archive_granularity`. A value of `0` is single folder, and a value of `1` is yearly or monthly.